# Add glue points to table in Libreoffice Draw

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-draw

Is there a way to add glue points to table in Libreoffice Draw ? There are 4 standard glue points but I cannot add extra ones. By table I mean the object that you obtain by clicking Insert->Table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find a way to do this directly.  As a workaround, create a rectangle with no fill that is the same size as the table.  Select the rectangle and the table and go to `Modify -> Group`.  Then add glue points to the rectangle as needed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did eventually.